# Show BroadcastReceiver data in progressBar

Tags: android, listview, broadcastreceiver, android-progressbar

I'm trying to display wifi data. Well I'm getting data from a broadcastReceiver, then I'm trying to display it in a listView and to show the wifi signal Strength in a progressBar. Every time there I new data in onReceive method , the list and the progressBare have to be updated.

But the progressBar is just working in the first item, like in this picture.

[image]

An this is the activity i'm using :

```
    public class WiFiScanResult extends ActionBarActivity {
    ListView list1 ;

    Receiver receiver = new Receiver();

    List<ScanResult> results ;
     private ProgressBar progressBar;
     int channelNumber;
     private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        WifiManager wifi;
        Button      enab;
        String resultsString ; 
        String[] myStringArray;
        int aa = 10;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wi_fi_scan_result);
        ConnectivityManager cxMgr = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listWifi);


        registerReceiver(receiver,new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));


    }

    public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("onReceive","onReceive");


        if(intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)){
             results = wifi.getScanResults();

         }
        MonAdaptateurDeListe adaptateur = new MonAdaptateurDeListe();

         list1.setAdapter(adaptateur); 
    }
    }

    private class MonAdaptateurDeListe extends ArrayAdapter<ScanResult> {
        int pos ;
        TextView text;
        public MonAdaptateurDeListe(){
            super(WiFiScanResult.this,R.layout.item_layout,results);
        }


        @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View itemView = convertView;

            if (itemView == null){
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
            }


            progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            TextView textView4 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.level);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.network);

                    if (results != null)
                    { 
                        pos = position;
                        text = textView4 ;
                        text.setText(results.get(pos).level+"dBm");

                        Handler progressBarHandler = new Handler();



                        progressBarHandler .post(new Runnable() {

                              public void run() {
                                  progressBar.setProgress(10);
                              }
                        });

                        TextView textView1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.SSIDBssid);
            textView1.setText( results.get(position).SSID +"(" + results.get(position).BSSID +")");



            }

            return itemView;
        }

    }

    //We unregister the broadcastreceiver quand on termine
            @Override
            protected void onDestroy (){//à la sortie de l'app on annule l'enregistrement
                super.onDestroy();
                if (receiver != null) {
                      Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled broadcst receiver", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      WiFiScanResult.this.unregisterReceiver(receiver);

                }

            }

}
```

PS :When i put this code on the onReceive methode i get a result like in the picture ,

```
MonAdaptateurDeListe adaptateur = new MonAdaptateurDeListe();

         list1.setAdapter(adaptateur);
```

but when i put it in the onCreate methode i get an exception :

```
 05-14 15:58:26.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21044): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-14 15:58:26.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21044): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.debitdistance/com.example.debitdistance.WiFiScanResult}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-14 15:58:26.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21044):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
05-14 15:58:26.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21044):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
05-14 15:58:26.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21044):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
05-14 15:58:26.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21044):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
05-14 15:58:26.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21044):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
05-14 15:58:26.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21044):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
05-14 15:58:26.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21044):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
05-14 15:58:26.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21044):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-14 15:58:26.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21044):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-14 15:58:26.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21044):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
05-14 15:58:26.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21044):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
05-14 15:58:26.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21044):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-14 15:58:26.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21044): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-14 15:58:26.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21044):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)
05-14 15:58:26.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21044):    at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:466)
05-14 15:58:26.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21044):    at com.example.debitdistance.WiFiScanResult.onCreate(WiFiScanResult.java:67)
05-14 15:58:26.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21044):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
05-14 15:58:26.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21044):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
05-14 15:58:26.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21044):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
05-14 15:58:26.232: E/AndroidRuntime(21044):    ... 11 more
```

Which point on : list1.setAdapter(adaptateur);

Comment: Hi. Can you submit your whole stack trace for the error. Is this code alpha/beta or production. The reason i ask is there is things you can do to make your life easy if you just restructure your code a bit(just a suggestion).

Comment: I added the hole stack trace (in case i put list1 in the onCreate). And any sugggestion to make this code better and simplier will be very helpful for me. Thank you @Pintac

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your result is null in "MonAdaptateurDeListe" if you put it in create.

Rather pass the list(new Arraylist) to the adapter when creating and then set list when in receive.

Also more on a design note. Your "MonAdaptateurDeListe" knows to much about the activity it is very tightly bound. Try making your "MonAdaptateurDeListe" independent off the activity that uses it.

thanks